# call super class constructor with same final class argument

Tags: scala

I dont remember how can I call super to the super class having final and super class same constructor

Here my code

```
class RestConnector(connectorProperties: Properties) extends BaseSyncConnector(connectorProperties) {

  def this(connectorProperties: Properties){
    this(connectorProperties)
   //Logic
  }
```

But it´s telling me

```
Error:(22, 5) ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both constructor RestConnector in class RestConnector of type (connectorProperties: java.util.Properties)RestConnector
and  constructor RestConnector in class RestConnector of type (connectorProperties: java.util.Properties)RestConnector
match argument types (java.util.Properties)
    this(connectorProperties)
Error:(21, 7) constructor RestConnector is defined twice
  conflicting symbols both originated in file 'RestConnector.scala'
  def this(connectorProperties: Properties){
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Ambiguity

The ambiguity is caused by the definition of two constructors for the class `RestConnector` :

- `class RestConnector(connectorProperties: Properties)`
- `def this(connectorProperties: Properties)`

This issue is that the compiler does not know which constructor to choose.

#### Super is already called

Moreover, you don't need to add the call to super because super is already called by this code : `... extends BaseSyncConnector(connectorProperties)`

Here is a example :

```
scala> class A (b: String) { println(s"b : $b") }
defined class A

scala> class C(bb: String) extends A(bb) // <- call to super constructor (`A(bb)`)
defined class C

scala> new C("hello")
b : hello // <- you can see here that A's constructor is called 
res0: C = C@7e2f86e6
```

#### What you can do to solve your issue

So, what you can do is :

```
class RestConnector(connectorProperties: Properties) extends BaseSyncConnector(connectorProperties) {
    // put the logic here
}
```